# Website loads with interruptions

Tags: website

Strange problem today when surfing websites hosted on my server. Everything works fast, server load is under 1, I don't see any problems on the server but...

I open some website and it starts loading very fast. Then it stops for no reason. After some time (10 seconds, 20 seconds, 1 minute) website continues loading. Sometimes it leads to "connection reset" error. It happends not on each click - I make 10-20-30-50 clicks and everything loads for 100% but on the next click page loading stops and continues after some time. When page hangs and I click refresh, it loads for 100% without any problems. Or I can open the same file in a new window/tab and it loads very fast. But previous window/tab is still loading.

Ping doesn't show any packet loss. I tested file loading through FTP. I loaded 300 MB file very fast and without interruptions.

It looks like data stuck somewhere between server and my computer.

I remember I had the same problem in the same data center ~5 years ago but I don't remember how I resolved it.

What is it? Server problem? Network problem? Internet service provider problem? Computer problem?

Comment: Please define "Strange problem today when surfing websites hosted on my server".  Is this a Linux or Windows server?  Is this a shared hosting environment?

Comment: Debian, dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

Is it happening with other sites or just your own ones hosted on your server?

I had something similar happen once, and resetting my WiFi router helped. I ended up getting a new router after a few weeks of erratic web surfing problems, and that seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: There are 3 websites on that server. It's happening with all 3 websites. Now it's 1:39 am here and the problem appears not so often but still persists. I doņ't use Wi-fi.